# Summation over 3 lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have three lists. As an example,

```
a = {10, 5, 6, 8, 7};
b = {4, 8, 9, 7, 9};
c = {7, 5, 12, 4, 1};
```

I want to get:

$$
x(i)=\sum _{i=0}^i\frac{1}{2}\left(a_ib_i+a_{i+1}b_{i+1}\right)\left(c_{i+1}-c_i\right)
$$
$i$ goes from $1$ to $4$, i.e. I want to get: $x(1)$,$x(2)$,$x(3)$ and $x(4)$.

So, I used the following code:

```
x=Sum[1/2*(a[[i]]*b[[i]] + a[[i + 1]]*b[[i + 1]])*(c[[i + 1]] - 
c[[i]]), {i, 1, 4}]
For[i = 0, i < 4, x, Print[x]]
```

But, I didn't get expected output. Could anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Table[Sum[1/2*(a[[i]]*b[[i]]+a[[i+1]]b[[i+1]])*(c[[i+1]]-c[[i]]), {i,1,k}],{k, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: Since I want to find $$y (i) = (Subscript[a, i + 1] - Subscript[a, i])/(
 Subscript[b, i + 1] - Subscript[b, i])$$ I tried with this code: `Table[(a[i + 1] - a[i])/(b[[i + 1]] - b[[i]]), {i, 1, k}], {k, 1, 4}` But I didn't get an error. Could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: @TMH you seem to be confusing `a[i]` and `a[[i]]` in that code. Try: `Table[Sum[(a[[i + 1]] - a[[i]])/(b[[i + 1]] - b[[i]]), {i, 1, k}], {k, 1, 4}]` ; incidentially this looks rather nice if you select the expression and convert to StandardForm.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. It works. but, I don't want a sum. So, I removed it. I actually don't know how to convert the expression into standard form. Really appreciate your help on that too.Thanks again.

Comment: @TMH I see.  Does the rest of the code work for you?  You can make the conversion from the menu **Cell** > **Convert To** or with the keyboard shortcuts listed therein.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes,it does.Thank you Mr.Wizard. I actually typed it in standard form and then copied to here. Then,it looked like in this form. I actually tried with "copy as Input text",even then it's same. Is there any other way to show it in standard form?

Comment: @TMH When posting here it is best to use InputForm as that is most easily (and correctly) copied.  To show what you are actually seeing you can **Save Selection As** an image and upload that (made easy by Szabolcs's image uploader, sadly broken at the moment).  Sometimes it nice to copy as LaTeX, which it appears you are already familiar with.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I got you. Thanks a lot Mr. Wizard.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sum[1/2*(a[[i]]*b[[i]] + a[[i + 1]]*b[[i + 1]])*(c[[i + 1]] - c[[i]]), {i, 1, 4}]
(*
-(739/2)
*)
```

But I think this is better:

```
Tr[Differences@c (Most[a b] + Rest[a b])]/2
```

Comment: `MovingAverage[a b, 2].Differences[c]`

Comment: @J.M. and belisarius Thank you for the answers. But, I want to get x values for each i values. i.e. I want to get values for x(1),x(2),x(3) and x(4)
Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @TMH thats the easy part: `x[i_]:=MovingAverage[Take[a,i+1] Take[b,i+1], 2].Differences[Take[c,i+1])]` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Based on J. M.'s comment:

```
MovingAverage[a b, 2] * Differences[c] // Accumulate
```

> ```
> {-80, 249, -191, -(739/2)}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just a variant:

```
Needs["Developer`"]
Accumulate[
 Times @@ MapThread[
   PartitionMap[Function[x, #2.x], #1, 2, 1] &, {{a b, 
     c}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {-1, 1}}}]]
```